# App to send group MMS without reply all

Tags: applications, mms

I am looking for an app that can send a text to multiple recipients without them being able to respond back to all the other recipients. And also not see who else received the message. Similar to sending out an email with BCC recipients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eduardo you are right, there is already a way to do this with the standard Messaging app. You have to disable the "Group messaging" setting in the Messaging app. Not sure if this setting is available on all versions of Android but I have v4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

SMS and MMS are 1 to 1 messages. Doing what you want it's standard. Just send the message using the standard SMS client. It's lets you send to multiple recipients, but it sends a individual message to each.